# sphinx.conf escaping hash (#) character

Tags: sphinx

How can I escape the # character in sphinx.conf ?

hash (#) is used to write comment

how would I write something like:

```
sql_host            = localhost
sql_user            = tuser
sql_pass            = abcd#ss4
sql_db              = tdb
```

please note the # in the sql_pass value "**abcd#ss4**"

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isnt a direct way to escape it.

Maybe create a new user with a different random password for sphinx to use.

Answer (score 0):

did you try using 'abcd#ss4' ? because Mysql supports that structure, if that doesnt work would you try with escaping characters? abcd#ss4